# Iphone resolution on an Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

We have an app that has been rejected in the review process by the Apple app review people. The cause for the rejection is that the app is not scaling properly when run on an Ipad.

The app was never meant to be run on an Ipad, but there seems to be no point in arguing with them about that.

Apple sent us a couple of screenshots that show our app being run on an Ipad with the top portion of the view cut off. Notice how the app is run in some mode where it looks like an Iphone app and does not fill out the entire display area. When we bring up the app on an Ipad, it fills out the screen and does so without any edges cut off.

Can anyone please tell me how to run the app on an Ipad the way the Apple guys have - Iphone-sized? We believe we have a fix for the issue but we need to reproduce the error and then be able to verify that the fix solves the issue.

(the logotypes in the images are intentionally blurred)

[image: Image from Apple]
[image: How we see it]

Comment: can't you setup the app to only run on iPhones and that's it. If it is not intended to run on iPads...

Comment: possible duplicate of [App store review guidelines 2.10 - should iPhone app be adjusted to iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593410/app-store-review-guidelines-2-10-should-iphone-app-be-adjusted-to-ipad)

Answer (score 5):

I just went through this myself and here is how I resolved it:

1. Go into info.plist and see if any of the supported interface orientations are set for iPad. Despite selecting iPhone only, I had iPad supported orientations for four (portrait, portrait upside down, landscape left, landscape right). I deleted those.
2. I also deleted any reference to the launch screen in the info.plist. My app is pretty simple and there's no preloading of data so I don't really need a launch screen. If you do, you could go old school and make your first VC the launch screen.
3. I then made these changes in Target-->General-->App Icons and Launch Images

[image]

That was the only way I could get it in the sim to run the app at iPhone resolution while running an iPad (iPad2, iPad Air).

If Apple is going to force developers to ensure an app runs on an iPad even if it is made just for iPhone, they should eliminate the iPhone Only and Universal options and just have iPad Only as an option.

Answer (score 1):

To run an iPhone app on an iPad, you just need to:

1. Acquire an iPad (you can also use the simulator)
2. Set the target device family in Xcode (it's under your target) to iPhone
3. Connect your iPad, perform any necessary certificate dances
4. Run the app on the iPad.

As long as the target device family is set to iPhone, the iPad will show your app in this mode.

Comment: Not as straightforward as this.

Comment: Mind elaborating @cheznead?

Comment: I just had my app rejected for this same reason. I had target device as iPhone, added telephony key in info.plist for sms log in, ran the app on iPad simulator, and it is not laying out correctly. So you need to make the app lay out correctly. It doesn't seem to be a case of just specifying target device family, etc.

Comment: Of course, @chez. The goal of the question is to run the app so you *can* test/fix the layout.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I guess I am very frustrated and flying off the handle since I have clients down my neck! sorry!

Comment: No worries :) Good luck with your issue.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan That's exactly what this does. Switching the device family to iPhone forces the app to run in iPhone mode on iPads - or at least it did in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is likely running your app on a simulator, not on a real device. Notice the "2X" on the top right. In XCode - you should run the app on iPad Retina Simulator. On the bottom right you will see a button that you can toggle from 1X to 2X.
If you place the simulator in "2X" mode, you will see what Apple is seeing.

What OS are you running on your iPad? Things have changed in iOS 8 - and that's likely why you're not seeing what Apple is seeing. My guess is that your are running an app that was initially developed for iOS 7 or earlier - which means that you need to upgrade from scaled resolution to native resolutions to resolve this issue. Here is how you do it:
[How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)