# Use Scaling Rather Than Native Resolution - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, iphone-6

Is there a way to create an app that still uses the scaling feature rather than the constrains and native resolution of the iPhone 6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable iPhone 6 native resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891277/how-to-disable-iphone-6-native-resolution)

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, i must have been looking for a good day or two and couldn't find anything so i presumed it hadn't been asked already. Although is there an easy way to disable the iPhone 6 resolution without creating a new project in Xcode 5.1.1 ?

Comment: If you already have a project (in Xcode 6), delete any iPhone 6/6+ launch images and any "Launch Screen file".

Comment: I haven't posted an answer. There's nothing to mark as correct.