# Xcode 7 - How to disable iPhone 6 native resolution?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, iphone-6

I want my app only to run in iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 resolution. In Xcode 6, you just needed to delete the Launch Screen file in order to lower the resolution (  [How to disable iPhone 6 native resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891277/how-to-disable-iphone-6-native-resolution#comment42383532_26837703))

However, now if you don't have a Launch Screen, your lower resolution apps will show up with black bars on top and bottom. So to fix this you have to add a Launch Screen Storyboard ([iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom))

Is there any way to run apps on lower resolutions without having these black bars show up?

Comment: No, you don't need the launch screen storyboard. You just need all the appropriate launch images. BTW - you really should support the iPhone 6/6+ screen sizes. As an owner of one of those devices, I hate apps that don't take advantage of the bigger screen.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton-- really appreciate it :)