# How to make app not scale at iPhone6 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, iphone-6

I notice that iPhone6 simulator will automatic scale App to fit the size of iPhone6. How to disable it? How to make iPhone6 know that the app can fit the size of it's screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)