# iPhone 6 Not Showing Full Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

In my iOS app that uses storyboards and auto layout but not size classes when I run the app in the simulator everything adjusts like it should with Auto Layout but when I put it on the iPhone 6 it runs at the iPhone 5S resolution scaled up to fit the screen size as if it doesn't know the app supports auto layout and will scale to fit the screen.

The Xcode project has a deployment target of 7.0 being compiled with Xcode 6 in case that matters. The iPhone 6 is also in standard zoom mode so any native Apple apps do run full resolution without scaling.

Does anyone know how I can fix it so that my app also runs full resolution?

Comment: so have you put iphone 6 launch images?

Comment: I also seem to be suffering from this. Creating a new project and running on my iPhone 6 looks fine (I can tell by the size of the status bar), but my current project is scaled up, and I can't find any settings that look any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the right search terms (and now understand what @nyekimov's comment means), it appears you need to supply a launch image for the iPhone 6(+) in one way or another.

The simplest way is to add a launch screen file (under App Icons and Launch Images on your app's target), since this can just be your main storyboard.

Another option seems to be adding iPhone 6(+) images to your launch screen assets catalogue (as pointed out by @nyekimov). You can add these in the sidebar by ticking the boxes under "iOS 8.0 and later": https://www.dropbox.com/s/i053lkwn5a9u61s/Screenshot%202014-09-21%2011.03.55.png?dl=0

I found both of these answers at [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)