# Status Bar too large on iPhone 6

Tags: ios8, statusbar

In my app on iOS8 on the iPhone 6 the status bar appears far larger than it does normally on the home screen or in other apps. This only happens on the iPhone 6, I've been looking into ways to fix this and I haven't found anything at this point. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. Below are pictures of the normal status bar and the status bar in my app.

[image: Normal]
[image: My App]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)
You will need to enable native resolution by updating the launch image. This should be what you need.