# iPhone6 status bar showing zoomed in app but not on home screen

Tags: ios, xcode6, uistatusbar, iphone-6

After some initial testing, our app on the iPhone6 we are seeing that the status bar (and maybe the whole app) is showing the zoomed size. When I say zoomed, I am referring to the desktop setting zoomed vs standard. The app was written using the older storyboard type, not the new one with Size classes.

My App:
[image]

Home Screen:
[image]

Comment: You'll see that with many apps. You'll need to update your app to support the new screen size.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is normal if you have not added iPhone 6/6+ launch images. Your entire app, including the status bar is zoomed when run to fill the screen. This has nothing to do with the "Zoomed/Standard" setting.

See [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) to learn how to enable native iPhone 6/6+ screen size support.