# UITableView (and its cells) seems to be zoomed on iPhone6/iPhone6+

Tags: ios, uitableview, iphone-6

I've encountered a strange behavior. I began to develop an iPhone app months ago, back when iOS8 and iPhone6 were not out. But now that I've an iPhone 6+ with iOS8, all the tableviews in my app seem to be kinda "zoomed". So I tried to copy & paste my tableview code on a new fresh project and here are the results :

My app : [image: Cells seem to be zoomed]

Test project with **same** code : [image: cells are fine]

We can clearly see that the tableview in my app is bigger. And as I said I'm using the exact same code to generate this TableView, so what's wrong ?

I tried to convert my app to Xcode 6 size classes but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

P.S : I'm developing my app on the last Xcode version (6.1)
The cells I'm using are just standard UITableViewCell

Comment: is the app "optimized" for iPhone 6 already?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983216/iphone6-status-bar-showing-zoomed-in-app-bot-not-on-home-screen it's the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a LaunchImage *.xib* in your project. Otherwise the 6-Plus treats your app as running on a plain iPhone 6 and zooms it up.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: yep, that's what i thought... it needs to be "optimized" for iphone 6 by including the properly sized launch image

Comment: It isn't really an optimization; it's just a signal to the device that you have read the docs. :)

Comment: Same thing was true of the 4-inch when it first came out; without an appropriate launch image you were letterboxed as if you were running on a 3.5-inch screen.

Comment: i know, that's why i put it in  quotation marks ;)

Comment: @nburk I know you know! :)))

Comment: Thx for the quick response and indeed it solved my problem... my bad to not read the doc entirely ;-)
I'll mark as accepted when I can !