# iPhone6, iPhone 6 plus: What naming convention the new images have to follow?

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

For iPhone4-5, we have to have 3 default images to be loaded by the device

```
Default.png
Default@2x.png  and
Default-568h@2x.png
```

IS there any naming convention for iPhone6 and 6 plus?

Comment: Until now I've only got it working with [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus - the answer by William Jockusch shows how to add the images without using the Launch Images asset catalog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of relying on filenames, you should use the asset catalog to provide default images and app icons.

There is an extensive guide by Apple about this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html

Comment: This page has everything about Asset Catalogs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1