# How to display iOS app on iPhone 6 without zoomed mode

Tags: ios, iphone-6

This might be a vague question, so let me know if you need screenshots.

I just got an iPhone 6 and I have it setup on "standard" zoom mode. This makes all text, icons and Apple apps display "small" as intended on the phone.
However, all other apps (including my iOS 8 optimized apps and big name apps like Facebook and Twitter) display in "zoomed in" mode. It's very odd and distracting as everything on the phone changes to zoomed in, including the clock, battery level, cell phone signal...everything.

Does anyone have a clue on how to force a third party app to display in standard mode when the phone is in standard mode, and on zoomed-in mode when the phone is zoomed-in?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Why would this not be a programming question if the fix is in XCode for the apps I'm making?

Comment: Because you are asking, as user, not a programmer, how to force other apps to behave a certain way on the new iPhone. That's not a programming question. Now, if you had asked how to make your own app take full advantage of the larger screen, that would be a (duplicate) programming question.

Comment: Did you even read my entire question? "However, all other apps (including my iOS 8 optimized apps..."
I understand this is a duplicate question but I didn't know how to find the original one with the fix.

Comment: Yes, I read it. Again, where is the programming part of the question? You are asking how to make other apps (nothing about programming your own) behave a certain way depending on a setting on the phone. This is a user question, not a programming question. If you intend this to be a programming question, then update the question so you ask how to setup your own app so it can behave a certain way.

Comment: I don't care about fixing facebook or any third party apps as an end-user on my phone. I asked as a programmer to get a fix for my own apps (which are obviously third party apps) in code or xcode setup (as the what the answer is).

Comment: Are you asking about how to enable an app for 4.7" and 5.5" screens? Like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/

Comment: dude, this was 2 years ago...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't force an app to disable that scaling, they have to update and add support for the new resolutions.

Here's how it's done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755436/657104

Comment: How to handle zoomed display? Could you explain more

Comment: I'm having this same issue wherein iPhone 12 series the screen looks a bit zoomed while in other iPhones it looks in a standard way. Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Use this code to detect the zoom and show a informative popup to the user- 

var isZoomed: Bool { 
return UIScreen.main.scale < UIScreen.main.nativeScale 
}