# Startup screen for iPhone 6 & plus showing the good one then briefly showing Default-Portrait@2x~iphone.png

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I didn't want to introduce an asset catalog. So I added images in Info-plist (as specified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799824/193181)). It works, the native resolution of iPhone 6 (&plus) are recognised, but 
I have a problem :

it shows first the startup screen Default-667h@2x.png and then briefly shows Default-Portrait@2x~iphone.png. Very ugly...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "~iPad" (without quotes) at the end of names of launch images for iPads. So you should have files:
Default-Portrait@2x~iPad.png
Default-Portrait~iPad.png