# Text Scaling on iPhone 6/6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

It seems like fonts other than the system font will be scaled up rather large on the iPhone 6 (particularly plus). Is the way to deal with this just to use smaller sized fonts when on a large screen? In my case I'm primarily using Arial-BoldMT. Similarly, the default keyboard is scaled up as well. Is this due to the same issue? Thanks!

Comment: Fonts are only scaled if the entire app is scaled. If you provide native support for the iPhone 6 and 6+ screen sizes, nothing is scaled.

Comment: Oh interesting! So what does it use to determine support? Like is it primarily just having views that are the width of the screen?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus