# unable to get width Height of the View on XCODE 6

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

```
NSLog(@"the View Weight is --%f--",self.view.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"the View Height is --%f--",self.view.frame.size.height);
```

I ran the same code using iPhone 4S, 5 , 6, 6S

on iPhone 4S it gives 320,480

but for all other Devices its giving me  320 , 568 . No matter 5, 6, 6S

Is this Xcode 6.0 Bug?

Even
      NSLog(@"the height is -%f-",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) gives m,e 568 on iPhone 6

Comment: Where you writing this in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear ?

Comment: No, on 6 Plus it should be 414 * 736

Comment: @ParagShinde Yes I am writing it in Did LOAD

moreover  NSLog(@"the height is -%f-",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height) givers 568 on iPhone 6

Comment: I have also faced same problem for it I resized view in viewWillAppear. So try it in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear. Best option is viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not configured to run on the larger devices, so it is running in zoomed mode with a logical screen size the same as the iPhone 5.

You need to add a launch image xib to enable support for larger devices as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: I am not getting you. every thing is perfect fine. what should I do?

Comment: @jturton Cannot I add Splash screens in the Image Asscets Directly?

Comment: I think so, don't the answers on the other question help you?

Comment: Issue Resolved... Added the new splash screens via Image Asscets 1. 750 X 1334
2. 1242 X 2208 and Now its working fine... Thanks @jrturton nice solution, working...and ur stackoverflow reputation 63.9K OMG!!