# iPhone 6 / 6 Plus images and text are blown up

Tags: android, jquery, ios, iphone, mobile

I'm using JQM to build apps with the help of Phonegap Build. Today I got my iPhone 6 Plus and it looks like apps are blown up a bit. On my Oneplus One everything looks ok:

iPhone:

[image]

Oneplus:

[image]

Can this be fixed? What is the problem? iPhone, Phonegap, jQM?

Answer (score 0):

The images need to be 3x resolution. You could also add a launch image at that resolution to activate it. Perhaps [this](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25754942/4106164) might help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like al the iPhone 6 does is show the same app, but make it larger (what I call blow up in the title). You would think a larger display would show more content, right? The image I'm using is shown the right way.

I'm not sure but I think this has something to do with jquery mobile not being able to handle the 2 and 3 pixel ratio. Android doesn't have this issue? Maybe wait for a new version of jquery mobile or use media queries in the meantime?

The other strange thing is the statusbar which seems to be larger in the app than outside or in other apps. Guess this is a phonegap thing seeing they create the webview?