# iPhone 6 vs >iPhone 5 nav bar heights

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

When running one of my apps on the iPhone 6, I've noticed the nav bar height of my app is taller than the nav bar height of a system app (ex Settings). While looking at some third party apps, I've noticed some apps have the same nav bar height as system apps (Twitter), and some apps have the same problem I do (Instagram).

This makes me believe that some of the apps are explicitly optimizing for iPhone 6, and some apps are just being scaled by the platform. Is there a specific way to optimize for iPhone 6?

This isn't an iOS 8 problem, as I've ran my app on an iPhone 5 running iOS 8 and the nav bars matched.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide launch images for iPhone 6 and 6+ (or a launch `xib` file).  See here: [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: This should be a duplicate flag, not an answer