# convert iOS app for iPhone 5s to iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I tried to convert my iOS app which is developed for iPhone 5s to iPhone 6. I thought it is quite simple. I changed the size of view controller in storyboard to `iPhone 4.7-inch` and started the iOS simulator for iPhone 6. But the result is that the content is still displayed in an iPhone 5s style and not in iPhone 6 style. The iOS simulator starts with the right size but the content is not correct.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: You need an iphone 6-sized launch screen

Comment: And how do I create those launch screen? Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) a right link?

Comment: Yea that workaround works too :]

Comment: it was the right info :)