# Stretched interface on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-6, launchimage

On my iPhone 6 Simulator (not iPhone 6 Plus) the interface looked stretched. I can't figure out why.

I created a clean new project and started the simulator and there the interface looks normal. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

So I copied the storyboard of the new project into my current project and started the simulator with the new storyboard. There it looked stretched up again:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was: There was no launch image (or a launch screen file) provided in my Xcode settings.

If that is the case the iPhone will resize the user interface.

Comment: The answer is also given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)