# Detecting iPhone 6 and plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mainscreen

I know there is some questions like this but i got no solution. I am trying to understand if it is iPhone 6 or not.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
```

When i try this it return IS_IPHONE_5 is true even in iPhone 6.  If i try native.scale iphone 5 and 6 also return 2, only iphone 6 plus returns 3. So i cant get it if it is iphone 6 from height or from scale.

```
 NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
```

They are all return same in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. So how to detect it?
any help please.

Comment: Why would you detect the iPhone the app is running on? There is no need, you can use AutoResizemask or auotlayout to fix your UI correctly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Comment: What exactly you want to accomplish detecting the user's device. Maybe your are following the wrong approach for your app.

Comment: Why is the SO community so heavy handed all the time?  I've up-voted you back up to zero...  I'm not sure why you would want to detect  the iPhone version, but just because I can't fathom a reason you might want doesn't mean I should righteously declare that you should *never* do it and slap you on the wrist.  What people are saying is valid.  The linked question above will probably lead you to the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @dave It is fine you downvoted or upvoted. I m working on old project which i did not write. Code is completely mess and if i could detect iphone model i could easly change size of background view. There is no xib or storyboard. Everything created programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support native resolution on iPhone 6/6+ you need to either

- provide properly sized launch images
- provide XIB file for launch screen