# How to support app for iphone 6 and iphone 6++

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store, iphone-6

my app is live on itune appstore but its showing that it is compatible upto iphone 5/5S. But i had tested the app on iphone 6 and 6++ simulators and it is working fine.

What i have to do so that it should show that this app is compatible with iphone 6 and 6++

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: In Xcode, go to your target, general and add the launch screen file.

Comment: There's an iPhone 6 Plus *Plus* now? Is it bigger than an iPad mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus compatibility, either you need to use a `LaunchScreen` file or simply add Launch images for 6/6Plus. Now when you try to run the app, it will automatically detect screen size and you can clearly see the app in correct dimension and size.