# Touch ID dialog showing a second status bar

Tags: ios, ios8, uistatusbar, touch-id

When I let the user login into my app with Touch ID, I get the dialog (which by the way is very ugly and cannot be customized) and I also get a second status bar, which looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to hide the status bar?
If not, set the status bar style to my style (`UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`)?

(I also would be very happy if someone knows of a way to customize the dialog, more than just changing labels)

Comment: Did you get any solution?? I am facing the same issue. IF you have solved this,  can you please post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this

just hide status bar when open touch id like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

not show after failure or success with perform selector with 1 sec delay like this and my code working perfectly

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this behaviour on iPhone 6/6+ ?
If yes, the way I solved it was by setting the appropriate launching xib so that iPhone 6 and 6 plus devices are using the native resolution without being scaled. (see also this question on how to do that [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) )