# Application is showing stretched keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

Can any one guide me that why my application is showing different kind of keyboard. keyboard for my app is large and like stretched.

this one image is for my app
[image: my app]

this one real keyboard in ios8
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running on an iPhone 6 or 6 plus and your app does not support those screen sizes, so it's running in scaled mode.

To support the new screen sizes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus).

Comment: no, my app support all size, i am using auto layout

Comment: how i can check? my app is running iphone 6 plus and it's showing my app screen according to that iphone 6 size

Comment: @Developer he gave you a link

Comment: thanks andy i had check that linked and had marked the question as answer