# uiview pixels looks different with same width

Tags: ios, uiview

i simply create numbers of UIViews with same width.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{

    UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50 + i * 10, 400, 1, 20)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```

it looks right on simulator but it's width looks different on iphone6
i think maybe it is caused by the screen rate?anyone knows why?

Comment: Is your iPhone app optimized for iPhone 6 ? (i.e. the screen has the correct scale and is not zoomed)

Comment: @KIDdAe how to optimized it, the default program size is 320*568.Do i have to change the scale factor or something.

Comment: Take a look at this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus/25755436#25755436