# Why are my views with Auto Layout applied continuing to scale up and not display at native resolution on larger-device simulators (iPhone 6 and up)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I'm a designer with a bit of Obj-C experience trying to help our engineers update a fairly large iOS app to use Auto Layout programatically, one view at a time.

I know that my constraints are working correctly, however when I preview them in the simulator, the updated views continue to scale up to fit the larger screen devices (iPhone 6 and up). Ideally I'd like to see the views that have Auto Layout displayed at the device's native resolution, and non-updated, frame-based views continue to scale.

Does Auto Layout need to be enabled globally somewhere or at a root view, and is there a recommended approach to converting to Auto Layout that will make the updates easy to preview at native res on the larger device simulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apps run in compatibility mode on iPhone 6 unless there is something to trigger the native scale.  There is more than one way to do this, but the one I remember at the moment is to add @3X graphics to the app icon image assets.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks! I ended up adding 2 new retina HD launch screens as recommended in [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821550/1043391) and now I can run at native res on iPhone 6/6+ simulators.