# my iOS app is in low resolution (status bar included)

Tags: ios, resolution, retina

I use an iPhone 6 and I launch Skype and my app. 
My app launches in low resolution (seems like non-retina) and Skype launches in high resolution - status bar resolution stays the same as in home menu of iOS, while the status bar in my app seems "bigger".

[screenshot](http://grab.by/EKMe)

The one on the left (mine) is clearly lower resolution.
What could be causing that ?

Comment: Did you optimize your app for iPhone6/6Plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Launch Screen or launch Images at correct resolution for iPhone 6 or 6 Plus, otherwise your application will run in 'display zoom' mode. (scaled up version from iPhone 5 or 4...)

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus), you can either :

- use a XIB that adapt to different screen resolutions
- use XCode Asset catalog 'LaunchImage' image set, and fill the correct sizes

Comment: What if I don't have a launch screen/launching image ?

Comment: See my edit : a XIB LaunchScreen is enough (although it's not compatible with iOS 7)