# Different app display resolution in debug mode and after deployment on test flight

Tags: ios, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.forms, testflight

after finishing an app I wanted to test it through Test Flight. I deployed the app to iTunes and after installing the application on the test devices it seems that in the app everything is "big" . More detailed:

I debug to an iPhone 6s and 5s and everything looks ok
I deployed the app to iTunes and testing on two different iPhone 6s the resolution seems to be very low
with the same deployment the resolution on 5s is great.
Take a look at those images:

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What type of splashscreen did you add? The supported resolution on iOS is determined by the splashscreen resolutions you have included. When you didn't include one that uses the full resolution of a device, the app will be switched into some kind of compatibility mode

Comment: Well, I left empty all the images for iOS 5,6. Do you believe that this could cause the problem?

Comment: It might, yes. The best option is to specify a storyboard splashscreen. This will scale to all resolutions

Comment: Hello @GeraldVersluis well yes that was the problem. I had to add launch screen images for all the resolutions and the problem solved. Thanks for the help

Comment: Upgraded it to an answer, please accept if it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of splash screen (or LaunchScreen in iOS lingo) did you add? The supported resolution on iOS is determined by the splash screen resolutions you have included.

When you didn't include one that uses the full resolution of a device, the app will be switched into some kind of compatibility mode.

See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) for all the resolutions that should be included, depending on the devices you want to support.

The best option is to specify a storyboard file as a splash screen. This will scale to all resolutions .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the launch image for iPhone 6s is at correct resolution.

The iPhone 6s (Retina HD 4.7) requires a portrait launch image of 750 x 1334.

[image]

References:

https://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28500520/5474400

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Answer (score 0):

Well as the user @GeraldVersluis posted in comment below my answer:

> The supported resolution on iOS is determined by the splash screen resolutions you have included. When you didn't include one that uses the full resolution of a device, the app will be switched into some kind of compatibility mode

That means, that I had to add an image for all of the iOS versions and the problem solved.