# Change UINavbar height from for older apps build using Xcode 5 or older

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode6, height, navigationbar

I've noticed the navigation height for the apps that I started with Xcode5 and older is larger than if i create a new application using Xcode6. Is there a way to change the height of the navigation bar. I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about how the iPhone 6 & 6 Plus nav bars specifically or are you seeing this for all devices?

Comment: Yes @AdamPro13. I just noticed the issue is on iphone 6 & 6 plus. I compare heights on mail app and my app and they are different heights on 6& 6plus but equal heights on iphone 4s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add launch image assets for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. This is a really good answer on how: [Enable Native Resolution on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)