# Keep UITableViewCell height in different IPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I don't understand how to keep heigt of rows in `UITableViewCell` in different screen sizes. I've setted to 50 my custom row Height, in the cell's `xib` and in the method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return 50;

}
```

But in IPhone 5 and iphone 6 Plus I'm seeing 8 table cell in the screen. I don't want to. I want the same row height and a lot of more rows in the IPhone 6 plus, like facebook app. How to achieve that?

Iphone 6:

[image]

Iphone 5:

[image]

I don't want the tablecell height different, i want moar tableview cells.

Comment: u want to increase the cell height for iphone 5?

Comment: Does your tableview have more than 8 rows, if you scroll? There are more rows than that, they're just not visible on the larger screen?

Comment: if the row is CGFloat 50 of height, i want 50 of height everytime. So, with different screen's height, i want more rows on bigger screen, and not larger rows.

Comment: Does the cellheight change based on screen size!!!!!!!!!?????it must be giving 50 only no all the time?

Comment: Looks like you need a launch storyboard or launch images for the 6 and the 6 plus, I'll bet your status bar is also larger too...

Comment: @DanielGalasko I don't understand. Just try facebook and you'll see that It isn't zooming the view of an iphone 5/5s in 6/6p, It will just show more contents.

Comment: Yes @fustalol but Facebook have updated their app to support the 6 and 6 plus. If you don't have a launch image or storyboard set then iOS will upscale the display:)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you haven't updated your App to support the 6 and the 6 plus. Thats why your display appears zoomed and you will notice that even the status bar is larger than normal. The quickest way to fix this is to add a launch storyboard, otherwise you can simply add launch images for the 6 and 6 plus. Just check this SO post - [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)