# Can't get iPhone 6+ Native Resolution

Tags: objective-c, screen-resolution, iphone-6-plus

I can't get my app to display iPhone 6+ resolution. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799824/4664671) but that only enables iPhone 6 resolution and not iPhone 6+. I also tried putting the correctly named and sized launch images in my app and that also did not work. My app uses no storyboards so I'm trying to find a programatic solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no programmatic solution: if the correct default images or a NIB is found then the app will be launched aware of the full resolution of the screen (i.e. 736 points). Otherwise it won't be. Your code is not run prior to, or as part of that decision.

If your app isn't seeing a display size of 736pt along the longer edge then you haven't included the correct launch images.

However the modern advice around default images would simply be: don't use them. Supply a LaunchScreen.xib. Then you're not responsible for hitting every single resolution that you want to support.