# Forcing iPhone6 to take 3x or Retina4 2x graphics

Tags: ios, iphone-6

Is there a way by which we can programmatically enforce iPhone 6 device to take either Retina4-2x or 3x graphics instead of 2x graphics from asset catalog? Presently, I noticed that iPhone 6 is picking 2x graphics, instead of Retina4-2x.

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: Testing it on iPhone6 simulator. I have a different image for 2x and Retina-2x in asset catalog. 2x image is shown on Iphone6 simulator.

Comment: Check this answer. [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 6 uses 2x graphics because it can only display up to such density. Retina4-2x and 2x has no difference, its the same scale.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the excellent article at [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified). However, it would seem you're missing the fact that iPhone 6 uses @2x and iPhone 6+ uses @3x.