# Native UIKeyboard is stretched for no reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I am having trouble with the UIKeyboard element. The keyboard is stretched vertically, this happens on every view where I have a keyboard. I have attached a screenshot of a normal sized keyboard from a blank example and the keyboard in my app.

[image: my app on the left, blank example on the right]

Thank you

Comment: Which Simulators are you using? 6 plus? 6?

Comment: I'm using the simulator for the 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left keyboard is standard for 4-Inch screens and the right is standard for 4.7-Inch screens. You likely have not adapted the left application for iPhone 6 yet, so its running a scaled up 4-Inch version.

Basically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) explains how to make your app so it runs at native resolution (basically how to upgrade an existing app).