# Native resolution on iPhone 6, works on simulator but not on device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator

I'm having some problems enabling native resolution on the iPhone 6 on the actual device itself, when I run in the simulator it runs at native 375x667 (verified by both launchscreen and nslog of viewcontroller size.

> 2015-04-29 13:24:24.220 aqrew_ios[7851:1294675] ViewController:didLayoutSubviews() - Width=375.000000 Height=667.000000

However when I run the same code on an actual iPhone 6 (iOS8.3) its running at scaled iPhone 5 resolution.

> 2015-04-29 13:17:02.614 aqrew_ios[720:179633] ViewController:didLayoutSubviews() - Width=320.000000 Height=568.000000

I've been through the [SO How to enable native resoltuion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) and have the following in the LaunchImage assets setup and working, app is portrait only, iphone only:

[Launchimage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPzHT.png)

AppIcons are:

[AppIcon screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPJDA.png)

(I'm not allowed to post images as on this account (work) I dont have 10 rep points!)

However whilst it works perfectly on the iOS simulator its not working on the real device, would appreciate any ideas....

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into the device settings app, in the 'display & brightness' section there is a setting called 'display zoom' which can be set to standard or zoomed. When zoom is enabled an iPhone 6+ scales up an iPhone 6 sized window, and an iPhone 6 zooms up an iphone 5 sized one.

(This caused me some stressful hours a couple months ago)

Comment: Jef, thanks so much for the answer, that was it exactly.

its been enabled on my phone for so long I didn't even remember I'd enabled zoomed mode.

When I switch back to Standard then it works in native mode as expected. Sadly I'm not allowed to upvote you with my lack of reputation otherwise I would have. Thanks again

Kate