# blank view on top of Nav Bar in ios Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

How do i get rid of this top and bottem blank view ?
Evrything is set to none.

[image: Sc SHot]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. You can add a launch screen file that appears to work for multiple screen sizes. see [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: It's not an "issue", it's how the OS ensures apps that haven't necessarily been optimized for larger screen sizes are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add proper launch screen files to resolve your issue