# iPhone 6 plus simulator size classes in landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-simulator, size-classes, autorotate

I'm trying to incorporate some of my iPad UI elements into iPhone 6 plus's landscape mode. To do this, I am checking for a `horizontalSizeClass` of regular. But whenever I run the app in the iPhone 6 plus simulator, the horizontal size class always registers as **compact** in landscape mode. (Even the keyboard is a regular iPhone keyboard, not the special 6+ keyboard.) Is this intended behavior? (does this happen on the real device?) How can I test the transition to a regular horizontal size class in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the entire screen was scaled up, including the status bar - the app wasn't supporting the iPhone 6/6+ screen size at all. I followed the instructions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) to add a launch storyboard, which allows the app to use the native capabilities of the 6/6+.