# Views in storyboard do not resize properly on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I've checked a lot of different websites and stackoverflow answers, and I'm still stuck.

I developed an app for iPhone and iPad targeting iOS 7.1. I have two storyboards, one for each device. The app only displays in portrait mode. I cannot seem to get the app to display full screen on the iPhone 6 simulator.

I've tried numerous things, I followed the advice linked [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips) by adding a Launch Screen, setting the iPhone storyboard to auto layout and "use size classes", and . Not only does that not affect the size, but the Launch Screen doesn't seem to scale properly either. If I get it to fit the iPhone 6 it doesn't fit the iPhone 5 properly.

I've tried adding the proper launch images and I don't get any errors saying the wrong image resolution is present.

I've used the storyboard as a Launch Screen described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus).

Now, when I switched to "use size classes" I could manually extend the objects in the views to match up with the size of iPhone 6 (I have not tested it for 6s) but that makes it extend past the iPhone 5 boundaries. The only thing I can think of right now is to create another storyboard and detect if it's iPhone 6, but I would really like some other ideas.

Here's what it looks like for iPhone 6:

[image]

And here's what it looks like on iPhone 5:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best advice i can give u is 
Use default size class , the classic 600x600 and then use Auto Layout
Or do the reverse, take a 3.5inch size VC and apply Auto Layout on it. Everything will present itself quite perfectly if you can apply the right constraints

Here is a [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1) for an awesome Autolayout tutorial

Comment: Could you expand upon that please? I am using a square layout (thanks to "Use Size Classes") and that hasn't changed anything. Nothing is resizing) and when switching to freeform it says it's already 600x600. Still not resizing.

Comment: Use Autolayout, Giving u a link to an awesome tutorial plz check the edit

Comment: I'll try to run through this, but the first link I posted in my question is from the same person. It's a separate article but it suggests the same things, which I've already done (use autolayout and size classes). Maybe there's something else in here, so I'll check it.

Comment: Autolayout and size classes are separate stuff, size classes came to existence only after ios8 but autolayout has been there since ios5 i think, not sure about that.But still Autolayout is the sweetest thing around in all GUI based architecture

Comment: So, it's helping a little bit, with some extra finesse.