# Status bar font is bold for some reason

Tags: ios, statusbar, uistatusbar, nsstatusbar

The clock, carrier, battery part in my device is normal, like in 1st picture. When I open my app, after loading the app in memory it starts to animate and make the navigation bar bold and bigger font. I am not even sure if this is a good or bad thing, but I would like to know how this happened.

Here is how I setup the rootVC if it has anything to do with this issue:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window!.rootViewController = VCOrganizer.LaunchVCHolder
window!.backgroundColor = QorumColors.ThemeBlue        
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your app does not currently support the larger screen resolution of the iPhone 6/6 Plus.  Because of that, your app is being displayed in the zoomed "compatibility" mode commonly seen with older applications.

The best way to fix this is to add a Launch Screen .xib to your application target (see the screenshot below).  This xib should contain placeholder UI objects which represent the "empty state" of your application as it lauches.  This replaces the "Launch Image" approach used by older versions of iOS.

**Xcode Target Settings - General**

[image: Xcode target settings]

[Check out this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) about supporting the native resolution of the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8cmt41 I use it like this. and these are my launch images http://prntscr.com/8cmthv . Is there something I am missing? I don't use xib so I just want to use image if its possible

Comment: I'm not sure offhand if there's anything wrong there, but Apple strongly recommends that you use a Launch Screen File moving forward.  If you want, you can simply use a .xip that contains a UIImageView, and put the image in that.

I would also recommend that you check out the Apple HIG for Launch Images.  Note that your launch screen is not supposed to be a splash screen or branding.  It should be identical to the first screen of your app, minus text and variable UI elements.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html