# UINavigationBar aspect changed on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have realised my app is showing a different aspect on the navigation bar for iOS 9.

My app is landscape view always, and I am using a custom height:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    [super sizeThatFits:size];

    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, VFSNavigationBarHeight);
    return newSize;
}
```

It looks perfect on iOS 8 and iOS 7, but the content is not vertical aligned on iOS 9.

[image]
This is how it looks on iOS 7 and 8.

[image]
And this is exactly the same code running on iOS 9.

As you can see iOS 9 is moving down the content of the navigation bar, and I'm not sure why. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I wrote the same question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404463/status-bar-font-is-bold-for-some-reason

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the relation with both questions.

Comment: where did you set the VFSNavigationBarHeight ?

Comment: Did you put a break point to see the size it returns on both iOS9 and iOS 8 ?

Comment: I subclassed the `UINavigationBar` and `sizeThatFits:` is overriden