# React Native StatusBar size

Tags: ios, react-native

I faced with problem. My StatusBar in the app has zoomed like on screen below.

[image]

** App init:

```
    <Root>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={'dark-content'} />
      <App />
   </Root>
```

** React-native v0.55.4
** iPhone 8+

How to avoid this problem? Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per react-native docs status bar style `dark-content` type makes your text and icon bold.

[StatusBarStyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#statusbarstyle)

**default** - Default status bar style (dark for iOS, light for Android)

**light-content** - Dark background, white texts and icons

**dark-content** - Light background, dark texts and icons

In some case [lauch images/lauch storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404609/5461400) is reason for zoomed