# Enable fullscreenmode on iPhone6 with launchscreen doesnt work

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app and I want to support the new screensize from iPhone6 and 6+.
I read some articles online, but my iPhone6 ist still in scale mode.

My app has deployment target iOS7.
I added a new launchscreen.storyboard and added this in General Config.
In simulator it works great, but not on real device.

Is there something I forgot?

best regards

Comment: This will be useful : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Comment: Also it might be because you might have not added iPhone 6 and 6+ launch images

Answer (score 0):

Add two new launch images for iPhone 6 (750 x 1334) and iPhone 6 plus (1242 x 2208) respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that key window has proper size. Workaround is to set proper frame: [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]].

**iPhone 6** (750x1334):

Default-375w-667h@2x~iphone.png

**iPhone 6 Plus**: (1242x2208)

Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png

Default-Landscape@3x.png (For Landscape)

Comment: I dont want the resolutions from launchimages.