# iOS Interface Oversized in Xcode Application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I have recently been running into a problem with one of the iOS applications that I'm developing. The problem with this application is that UI elements appear to be oversized. In Xcode the elements could have the same default sizes, but during the simulation process the elements are almost too large to fit on the screen. Has anyone ran into a similar issue and figured out how to resolve it. I have attached pictures below that illustrate the problem more clearly. In one of the pictures below, the keyboard clearly appears to be larger than that in the other picture.

- [Oversized User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG1st.png)
- [Normal Sized User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOc2R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities

The device has Display Zoom turned on. You can change that in Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom.

You app doesn't have a launch image for that size. Either add a launch image for that screen size or use a launch storyboard/xib. [How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out trying to fix this error. It was the launch image that was the problem.