# Why does the iOS Status bar change size on some apps?

Tags: ios, statusbar

Main question:
This may be a simpleton question but I noticed on the lock screen the iOS status bar is bigger than the usual 20 points. Even when I turn location setting off and close all apps. the iOS lock screens status bar is bigger when compared to the iOS status bar when my iPhone is in an un-locked state. Why is that?

Second kinda related to the first question:
also when I open grabTaxi [found here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/grab-grabtaxi/id647268330?mt=8) the status bar is bigger than usual. Please download the app to see what I am talking about. you can't really tell by just looking at the screen shots.

Did the grab taxi developers decide to make their status bar bigger than the default?

Is it because grabTaxi is using some cross platform language, resulting in a bigger status bar?

Do apple make the status bar bigger on the lock screen simply because its easier to see?

Comment: Are you talking about the 1st screenshot of the linked app? The apparently taller than normal navigation/status bar? I'd almost say that's a bug in the app.

Comment: Your update still doesn't completely clear up the question. Perhaps you should add a screenshot of this larger status bar on the lock screen to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, apps that don't have a launch screen file, will have a bigger status bar. more detail here

[How to enable native resolution for apps on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Comment: Even if you have some launch screen images missing you will get this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If an app is using your location and you lock the device, and if the app continues to use your location in the background, a large status bar is shown to remind you that the app is still using your location.

Comment: Apps using location show a blue status bar when *not* using the app. The OP seems (I think) to be talking about the taller green navigation/status bar combo shown on the first screenshot of the linked app. That is unrelated to using location in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy I thought that at first too, but he explicitly said "the lock screen". The "lock screen" is a case of not using the app (the app is backgrounded). Hence my brilliant deduction.

Comment: The lock screen isn't mentioned until the very end of the question so it's hard to know what the OP is really asking. Hopefully they will clarify based on my comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone's status bar on lock screen is also bigger than normal, so I think Apple makes it bigger on lock screen for some reason.Maybe just because that it's easier to see.

For your another question, I downloaded GrabTaxi and used it. And maybe it's just because GrabTaxi doesn't adapt to 4.7-inch or 5.5-inch screen.