# Has 'Optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus' been removed by Apple?

Tags: ios9

We have tons of questions about how to get "optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus" label for your app in the app store. But now I see that none of apps familiar to me (mine and even facebook) display the label anymore. So has it been removed nowadays? Or do I have an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been removed.

Earlier, you could add it by adding either a launch storyboard or launch images — which you should still do. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25754942/1445366).)

Comment: thank you. It's good to hear that it isn't only my personal issue. I know how we should optimize apps, however was surprised to see that the label was removed, even not sure when exactly :)

Comment: @nyekimov I speculate that Apple will soon *require* support for larger iPhones.

Comment: ah, got it, before it was like a promotion campaign and now it is becoming a requirement, makes sense.