# text height different between IB and simulator

Tags: xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, ios-simulator

On a test drive app, I have a basic UIViewController (QZTestViewController) loaded with its xib file with only one UILabel centered by autolayout. This controller is opened from the home controller (QZHomeViewController designed in the default storyboard).

The problem is that the height of this label is smaller that the result on the simulator. See it in [XIB/Simulator comparison snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGNVt.png).

Any idea ? A small test project is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/788257/Label%20Height%20Test.zip) if someone can have a look and help me before I become crazy.

PS: Note that the simulated metrics is set to iPhone 5.5-inch in the XIB file and I run the simulator iPhone 6s Plus (9.3).

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com, including your test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the size of the status bar items on the Simulator (and double-checking your project), I can tell that your app is being upscaled to fit the screen. This is happening because **it's not properly configured to the 4.7" or 5.5" screens**.

To fix that and make it load with the correct resolution, simply add a LaunchScreen storyboard to your project. Go to your project settings, select your Target and in **App Icons and Launch Images** select a storyboard or xib file to **Launch Screen File**. This will make the app compatible with the larger screens' resolutions, and your button will have the correct size as it will not be upscaled :)

Comment: @chepiok When Apple introduced the new screen sizes, they decided that iOS would no longer use Launch Images (as you have set in your project), and instead use an Interface Builder file (such as a xib or storyboard) that can adapt to all different screen sizes instead of many different images. So it assumes that if your project still only uses Launch Images, it does not support the new devices. [Another question about that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)