# Status bar in application is bigger then normal

Tags: swift, swift2

I have problem with status bar. In my application is bigger than normal. Why? I don't use Storyboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using translucent UINavigationBar (it is contained in UINavigationController too)?.

Comment: It's simple controller (not NavigationControler) with some subviews.

Comment: Are you talking about the actual status bar(looks normal to me) or the light blue rectangle on top of your view?

Comment: About status bar. In application is bigger than normaly (see distance between wifi icon and time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus) out. Your launch screen is not provided in native resolutions so the app scales up. Change the launch screen for your target to your main storyboard and it should be fine.