# iOS - New keyboard style on a textview/textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have realised that the keyboard which appears on my application doesn't have the same layout/appearance than others on the same device.

Keyboard that appears on my app:
[image]
Keyboard that appears on Safari:
[image]

Both screenshots has been taken on the same device with iOS 10.2. The second keyboard has like a modern style with more keys but using less space on the screen.

I think it could be related to some configuration on the project. I have tried the same *textview* but on a new empty project and I'm getting the new keyboard layout.

This is the current textview configuration (yes, it's an old project that uses xib files)

[image]

Do you know what I need to get the new keyboard style on my app?

Comment: you have to add custom keyboard extension for that and need to develope own keyboard. [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)

Comment: @NiravHathi I have tried creating a project from scratch and just adding a TextView and the keyboard was the same than on Safari.

Comment: Is your app optimized for all dimensions of iPhone? My guess that your issue lies there. I think that the second screenshot is the optimized keyboard for landscape with iPhone 6/6+ size.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the answer. The keyboard has the old style even on portrait mode, so I don't think it's related to the Landscape version. Anyway, what do you mean by "optimized for all dimensions"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larme has said, the application was not optimized for iPhone 6/plus. Adding the following image size to the launch image was enough:

- **Default-667h@2x.png:** 750 x 1334 (iPhone 6, Portrait)
- **Default-736h@3x.png:** 1242 x 2208 (iPhone 6 Plus, Portrait)