# how to upscale Iphone 4in screen to 4.7/5.5in screen?

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok so my old apps which were written for the 3.5in and 4in iphone screens are downloaded on the and iphone with an 4.7/5.5in they seem to upscale and run perfectly fine with everything where it's suppose to be on the screen. So now I'm writing a new app just for the 4in screens because my thinking is that it will upscale when ran on 4.7/5.5in screen but this doesn't seem to be the case.

When I run my new app on a device with a 4.7/5.5in screen there is no upscaling. Why is this so? is there any setting to force the iphone to perform the upscaling or do I have to actually tune everything for 4.7/5.5in screens?

UPDATE:
Ok I figured it out. To get your apps designed for the 4in screen to zoom in/upscale to fit the 4.7/5.5in screens you have delete the LaunchScreen.storyboard file from your project and add the Default-568@2x file.

Comment: There is something called auto layout, check it out.  Can you show us some code? Or at least explain some **specific** issue you are having? (A `UIImage`? `CALayer`? Anything?)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus but I can't be sure with so little information.

Comment: tell me if this is your case.. old app use to zoom to fit the screen.. and newone doesnt?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic, Yup that's it. I think I figure it out though. I needed to add an launch screen with the "568@2x" name to force the new apps to zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS apps detect the screen size using the launch screen**. The made the OS zoom out the app in order to support older apps.
If you want **to let the app take full usage of the screen resolution** you should use a **LaunScreen storyboard** or **provide the assets for all the screen sizes**. If this assets are not found and you use the asset catalog for the splash screen you will get the zoom to fit larger screens