# App run on simulator does not respect points or fonts from storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, legacy

I am working on new features (with Swift) on a legacy project ( Objective-C ) project.

Everything that I am receiving from designer (dimensions in points, font dimensions) put into storyboard or xib files got bigger in **old project**.

In **SIMULATOR**, here is an example with a **uiview height** and **font dimension** for **iPhone 7**

[image]

We tried:

1. Designer gives all dimensions in points. He is currently designing for iPhone 7/6. I am using in storyboard iPhone 7 view.

**In a new project** the correspondence is 1:1. 
**In the legacy project** everything shows a little bigger.

What shall I search?

Comment: Do you use autolayout?

Comment: @J.Doe, yes. I am using. There is no difference from the storyboard in a brand new project or the one from the legacy project. Both images are taken from iPhone 7 simulator.

Comment: I suspect, somewhere is a scale, or something used to modify all dimensions. But I don't know what to look for

Comment: Since the project is legacy, I have to ask if this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755436/5099014

Comment: @AllenHumphreys, I am amazed that could be this one. Unfortunately, servers are stopped at this hour and I can not test it. But I've done that single modification, and layout is totally different. I'll tell you on Monday if this works out and if positive, I'll ask you for a detailed answer so that I can accept it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone 6 was introduced alongside iOS 8 and Xcode 6. As part of the introduction of the larger screen sizes, a legacy path was created that would allow older apps to run in a mode as if they were on an iPhone 4/5 screen size, simply scaling up the interface. This was intended to give app developers time to opt into the native, larger resolution of the iPhone 6 and 6 plus. In your question, I noticed this:
[image]

The larger battery icon is from your legacy app, while the smaller is from your brand new application. The contents of the status bar being scaled is a sure tell sign that the app is in this legacy mode. (Also, the interface often appears kind of fuzzy)

Therefore, I think your legacy app must have never adopted the launch screen storyboard or xib file that is needed to take advantage of the native resolution of the larger devices. To adopt it, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus/25755436#25755436).

Comment: is this a typo? " I think your legacy app must have never adopted", I mean the word "never".

Comment: So, this is the solution to have the launch screen file. But as a consequence I have to update all *.xib files :(