# Ionic 3 disable iOS display zoom

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I just can't figure out how to get rid of display zoom on iOS. Just to be clear, iOS has multiple places where bigger fonts/zoom can be enabled, but I'm talking about this:

> 1. Tap the Settings app.
> 2. Tap Display & Brightness.
> 3. Tap View in the Display Zoom section.
> 4. On this screen, you can tap Standard or Zoomed to see a preview of each  option. Swipe side to side to see the option in different scenarios so you can get a good idea of how it looks.
> 5. Make your selection and tap Set and confirm the choice.

This feature is intended to control iPhone5/iOS7 app behavior on iPhone6/iOS8+

What I've tried so far.

1. Regenerate all icon resources with `ionic cordova resources --force`
2. Fix all the app-icons and launcher-images (1. won't generate the proper sizes)
3. In XCode set the Project > General > App Icons and Launcher Images and verified that the AppIcon casset contains all the images for all versions
4. In XCode set the Project > General > App Icons and Launcher Images and verified that the Launcher Image casset contains all the images for all versions
5. Set the `Launch Screen File` to CDVLaunchScreen
6. Unset the `Launch Screen File` (empty)
7. In the {Project}-Info.plist removed the `Launch screen interface file base name`

related: [iOS8 native resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus/25755436#25755436)

Comment: Any progress on this?  I'm having the same problem