# App store review guidelines 2.10 - should iPhone app be adjusted to iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I find paragraph 2.10 of App store review guidelines a bit ambiguous. It says : "iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution"

My app is deployment target is iphone and the supposed device orientation is portait

[image]

When I tested my app on ipad simulator it looks as follows:

[image]

This is just a piece of the view to give you the notion of how it actually look like - the app view does not fit the whole frame of ipad simulator.

The reason why I got my app rejected is completely different, however I don't want to waste another 8 days to see the rejection again because of some weird issue, so that's why I ask. Moreover, do you know if they stop review when they encounter a problem? Or they always undeline all the issues?
My question is: should I do something with this ipad view even if my app's target device is iphone? If yes, what do you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because your app is not universal (it has been made for iPhone only), it won't be fully compatible with an iPad. Don't get me wrong, iPad will still be able to download the app from the App Store, but the app's screens won't perfectly fit the iPad's screen. It's an iPhone app, so iPad is just making the app's screen bigger. Just it. This is the case of an iPhone app running on an iPad.

Comment: But how appstore review will treat that case?

Comment: You just need to see if your app is 100% usable when running it on an iPad. You'll most likely be okay with just leaving it as is - the iPad basically emulates an iPhone when it detects apps that are not Universal.

Comment: It will just go along just fine. Apple accepts it. There are many apps that don't support iPad.

Comment: Well the app contains call option triggered on a button - so I gues one can't say its 100% usable on iPad, what's your opinion?

Comment: With iOS8 it is possible for the call button to work on an iPad - if the user has set the permissions the iPad can place a call using the user's paired iPhone

Comment: So, I shouldn't care about it, and what is most important, apple review wouldn't consider is as an issue, am I right?

Comment: If your app allows users to make calls from their iPhone what you should be doing is checking that the device you are running on allows calls to be made and if not either hide the button or show an alert telling the user they can't perform this action. If your iPhone app is running in x2 mode on an iPad it will still detect whether it can make calls or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPad will be able to download your iPhone app and run it, but **your app won't be fully compatible with it**. iPad users may encounter issues such as bugs and incompatible features.

iPad users will only be able to download your app from the App Store by **searching its name and filtering the search results** with "iPhone Only". Therefore don't expect full visibility.

Your iPhone app will run successfully on an iPad most of the times but it will be presented with a scaled screen.

[image]

Comment: Well the app contains call option triggered on a button - so I gues one can't say its 100% usable on iPad, what's your opinion?

Comment: Can you please explain further your first sentence? What kind of action is the app triggering?

Comment: there is a button which enables user to dial a number - this is not possible on ipads without cellulars I guess

Comment: What happens if you run the app on the iPad Simulator? By the way you can detect the device on which the app is running on, so if the user is using an iPad just him/her: "Sorry, you can't do that" (using an `UIAlertController`)

Comment: This is probably the right thing to do. Running my app on simulator is kind of crap because I keep getting error with core location. this is the simulator issue as far I know. So I test my app mostly on my device which is iphone 5