# How to disable iPad support?

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to disable iPad support for Xamarin.iOS application?

I have `iPhone/iPod` selected in my `Info.plist`:

[image]

And here is the source:

[image]

However, I am still able to run it on iPad Air simulator and my app got rejected because it didn't work well on iPad (it isn't supposed to, though).

What could be the issue?

Please ask me to add any information needed.

Comment: All iPhone/iPod App should run on an iPad in phone mode. This means that your app is not presented full screen but in a phone resolutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't fully disable iPad support because every iPhone app will also compatible with 3.5 Inch or iPhone 4/4S support screen resolution means your app run on iPad with iPhone resolution. So if your app is not supported 3.5 Inch then it will reject by Apple.  Check This link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28593581/6655153