# Can I make certain devices not able to download an app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

So I'm making an app on Xcode, but there are so many errors that I can't fix on the Ipad version, but the Iphones work just fine, is there a way when I submit my app for review to make Ipads not able to download the app? Or is that not a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disabled it from Xcode.Uncheck iPad item.It will fix your problem. You cannot submit and publish app with errors.

[image: Xcode]

Comment: yes..only iPhone version will review and only show on iPhones after publish.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is actually not going to work out very well:

[App store review guidelines 2.10 - should iPhone app be adjusted to iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593410/app-store-review-guidelines-2-10-should-iphone-app-be-adjusted-to-ipad/28593581#28593581)

If you want to prevent your app from being used on an iPad, then specify that you have a hardware requirement for Health Kit since it is unsupported on iPad, thus ensuring your app cannot run there.

The caveat here is that you must do this for your v1.0 submission since you cannot restrict an app after it is available.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW11

[image]